# Android: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I make an chat app for practice and
tried to use my add1.png image in my drawable folder as a default profile image whether user put the image or not

here's my code snipet

```
if (imageUri == null) { //when user has no image
                        //use default image as a profile image that in drawable folder
       imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                 "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.add1)
                 + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.add1)
                 + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.add1));
}

//insert into firebase storage
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("userImages").child(uid).putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {...}
```

In the event that run the app exception has occurred but the default image(add1.png) be inserted into firebase storage properly.

here's the exception.

```
 W/UploadTask: could not retrieve file size for upload android.resource://com.example.harag.myapplication/drawable/add1
          java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file
              at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:812)
              at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:749)
              at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
              at com.example.harag.myapplication.SignUpActivity$2$1.onComplete(SignUpActivity.java:92)
              at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

[image]

thank you!

Comment: getResourceEntryName doesn't return the extension, maybe that causes the problem?

Comment: Few things in Android support the `android.resource` scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UploadTask`.`UploadTask` which you can use to manage and monitor the status of the upload.

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    }
});
```

[Firebase Upload Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

Comment: why? I used onComplete method as a callback function doesn't it retrieve whether it successful or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.xyz.abc/drawable/myimage");
or 
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/drawable/myimage");
```

Comment: still same exception occur

Comment: Are you local image Upload to firebase storage?

Comment: Well it is in my drawable folder so it is local image